# /usr/share/openstack-dashboard directory is not created

Tags: django, openstack-horizon

my project involves horizon as the requirements and i dont see openstack dashboard being installed.

Horizon is installed as part of the dependency and horizon-2014.1.1.tar is picked locally. Can anyone tell is there anything i will have to do more.